# How to put result from pipe to Samba drive with smbclient?

Tags: libsmbclient

I would like to do something like this?

```
echo "test"  | smbclient //server/share -c "cd /target/location/;put <RESULT_FROM_PIPE> <AS_THIS_FILENAME>"
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 4):

Well finally, this is the solution I found:

```
echo "test"  | smbclient //server/share -c "cd /target/location/;put - <NEW_THIS_FILENAME>"
```

The trick is in the dash `-` which redirects the `stdin`.